flutter_web_bluetooth package is lagging to discover services
I recently ran into a problem on some specific browsers/laptop. The discover services of the package flutter_web_bluetooth is taking a couple of seconds to give a response meanwhile on most of the browser, the response is within one second. What could be the possible reasons to this?
Specs on a PC where it is not working correctly:
Edge 129.0.2792.65
Chrome 129.0.6668.90
Computer:
Windows 10 pro
Intel i5
RAM 8GB
Thinkpad T440
2.5GHz Base frequency
other computer:
Windows
Intel i5
RAM8Gb
HP Elitebook
2.5GHz Base frequency
